# How to add motion blur (non-zero exposure time rendering) in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, post-processing

I am trying to achieve this effect:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8554242/dmitri/projects/MotionBlurDemo/MotionBlurDemo.html

But I need it applied to my Three.js scene, specifically on a Point Cloud Material (particles) or the individual particles.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the **"physically correct"** approach then

1. create a **FIFO** of `N` images.
2. inside each scene redraw (assuming constant fps)

   1. if **FIFO** already full throw out the oldest image
   2. put the raw rendered scene image in the **FIFO**
   3. blend all the images in the **FIFO** together

      If you have big `N` then to speed things up You can store also the cumulative blend image off all images inside FIFO. Adding inserted image to it and substracting removing image from it. But the target image **must have enough color bits to hold the result**. In such case you render the cumulative image divided by `N`.
   4. render the blended image to screen

For constant **fps** is the exposure time `t=N/fps`. If you do not have constant **fps** then you need to use variable size **FIFO** and Store the render time along with image. If sum of render times of images inside **FIFO** exceeds the exposure time throw oldest image out...

This approach requires quite a lot of memory (the images **FIFO**) but does not need any additional processing. Most blur effects fake all this inside geometry shader or by **CPU** by blurring or rendering differently the moving object which affect performance and sometimes is a bit complicated to render.